# Is there a Python solution for finding a dataframe from a a column of a dataframe in a dictionary format?

Tags: python

A dataframe column is listed as below:

```
0    {'id': '6461', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T21:28:23.112179252Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6460', 'price': '0.85549', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
1    {'id': '6458', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T21:23:57.662166226Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6457', 'price': '0.85550', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
2    {'id': '6455', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T21:12:35.755193484Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6454', 'price': '0.85556', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
3    {'id': '6451', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T20:44:47.765450971Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6450', 'price': '0.85592', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
4    {'id': '6448', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T20:36:39.072854829Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6447', 'price': '0.85528', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
5    {'id': '6445', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T19:55:47.644077176Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6444', 'price': '0.85849', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
6    {'id': '6442', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T19:52:13.751798638Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6441', 'price': '0.85864', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
7    {'id': '6436', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T19:37:27.972316396Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6435', 'price': '0.85877', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
8    {'id': '6433', 'createTime': '2020-04-01T19:22:47.733529815Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 'tradeID': '6432', 'price': '0.85819', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'state': 'PENDING'}
```

[image]

1. Dataframe screeshot is as the attached image.
2. Question:
   How could I create a dataframe based on the output of stopLossOrder column?

Comment: Thank you for everyone. I find a line of code can solve the problem: df2 = df_stoploss_trade.stopLossOrder.dropna().apply(pd.Series)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already done getting that sets of data into a dictionary format, just create an array or list, and append each dictionary sets you're retrieving to the list.

Here's a sample:

```
# this is your data frame you are retrieving in a dictionary format
# i have just created a sample variable to demonstrate
data_sets = [{
             'id': '6461', 
             'createTime': '2020-04-01T21:28:23.112179252Z', 
             'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 
             'tradeID': '6460',  
             'price': '0.85549', 
             'timeInForce': 'GTC', 
             'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 
             'state': 'PENDING'
            }, {'id': '6458', 
             'createTime': '2020-04-01T21:23:57.662166226Z', 
             'type': 'STOP_LOSS', 
             'tradeID': '6457', 
             'price': '0.85550', 
             'timeInForce': 'GTC', 
             'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 
             'state': 'PENDING'}]

temp_list = []
frame_list = [] # declare to add to dataframe

for each_data_sets in data_sets:
    temp_list.append(each_data_sets)

for each_list_ds in temp_list:
    id = each_list_ds['id']
    createTime = each_list_ds['createTime']
    type = each_list_ds['type']
    frame_list.append([id, createTime, type ........]) # append them to make a two dimensional array
    ....
    ....

pd.DataFrame(np.array(frame_list), columns=['id', 'createTime', 'type', . . . . .])
```

I HOPE THIS HELPS !...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is really close to the final solution. I convert it to a list -- a format as you show me: data_sets = data_sets.values.tolist()

Comment: However, when I run the second loop, I get an error as below: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-69-3ed23adaf3db>", line 2, in <module>
    id = each_list_ds['id']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: As I have observed in your error, you are just slicing a list not a dictionary, in my code `id = each_list_ds['id']`, `each_list_ds` is a dictionary object inside a list variable, that's why I applied `['id']` kind of indexing to get the value of the **id** from the dictionary ...

Comment: How could transfer the dataframe column to your datasets format?

Comment: I have updated my answer .. If you still have any questions, and I am free, I will help...

Answer (score 0):

```
# get all column names
sample = df['stopLossOrder'].iloc[0]
columns = list(sample.keys())

# create a function for a single row
def create_col(row):
    global col_name
    return row[col_name]

# create columns in df
for col_name in columns:
    df[col_name] = df['stopLossOrder'].apply(create_col)
```

Comment: Hi Kate, Thanks for your answer. I get an error as below:Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-76-f01e75e474f2>", line 1, in <module>
    columns = list(sample.keys())

AttributeError: '_iLocIndexer' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: The dictionary is not well defined. The whole set of data is just items(), I believe.

Comment: Fixed the first one -- my typo, sorry. The second comment: `row[0]` should return the whole dictionary, `row[0][col_name]` returns value for the specific column,